# Why does the validation F1 score remain constant from the first epoch and outperform the training F1 score?

Tags: validation, deep-learning, pytorch, metrics, training-data

I am working on GNNs and when training something strange has caught my attention. When I train GNN models on different datasets, I've noticed that the validation F1 score remains the same starting from the very first training iteration. What's even more surprising is that the validation score consistently outperforms the training score.   (NOTE that : on another data set it works normally but when it comes to this ones any model gives the best result from the begging 98%)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vejqx.jpg)](https://i.stack[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nuBG.jpg).imgur.com/HlHT9.jpg)

I was expecting to have a nice validation curve !